# Processing sketches won't run online with java?

Tags: java, javascript, macos, applet, processing

I've recently been learning Processing, a sort of Java based visual language. It has a feature to export sketches/scripts as html documents and open them in a browser and run them with a java applet. However, when I try to open them (on a Mac OS X 10.5.8), it redirects me to the Java page telling me that Apple supplies its own version. I checked for software updates and tried downloading another version of Java to no avail. Also, I checked on a website to see if Firefox had Java, but it said it was disabled, despite my preferences having Javascript checked off.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: *"I checked on a website to see if Firefox had Java, but it said it was disabled, despite my preferences having Javascript checked off."*  Java and JavaScript are entirely separate matters (though sometimes JS will interact with a Java applet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running an unsupported version of Java, you need to update to 10.6 or higher to get the latest version. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3995956?start=0&tstart=0

This belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ as well.